# Restsharp (version >107) Data object is null

Tags: c#, restsharp

I've been using restsharp lately with an outdated version 106 and recently updated it to 108 and it seems that starting from 107 the object response.Data is always null. While the raw Content does have the JSON response as following:

```json
{
  "message" : "Login successful!",
  "expirationTime" : 1800000,
  "userId" : "userID",
  "token" : "token"
}
```

The exact same code works in v106 but starting from 107 the data is null.

Am I doing something wrong?

```cs
 private const string BASE_URL = "URI";
 private static RestClient client;

        public struct LoginResponse
        {
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string expirationTime { get; set; }
            public string userId { get; set; }
            public string token { get; set; }
        }
        public async static Task<LoginResponse> GetApiToken()
        {
            client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/login", Method.POST);
            var body = new
            {
                email = "email",
                password = "password"
            };

            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*+json");
            request.AddJsonBody(body);
            var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync<LoginResponse>(request);
            LoginResponse login = response.Data;
            return login;  
        }
```

Comment: Have you read https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107 about how to migrate to 107?

Comment: Hi I did indeed read this specific page and I was already using the correct methods. I suspect something wrong with the deserializer

Comment: Well, the page says: "By default, both XML and JSON are supported. Only change the Accept header if you need something else, like binary streams, or plain text.". Have you tried removing the accept header?

Comment: Hi it's a mandatory header for the REST query I'm using otherwise the StatusCode is NotAcceptable

Comment: RestSharp [chooses](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/30a07067a8b1b818e0bde0496fe33a888b0eb6dc/src/RestSharp/RestClient.Serialization.cs#L95) the serializer to use based on the Content-Type of the response (which in this case is probably invalid - `*+json` is not a valid content-type), or the first character of the response body. Can you check the content-type returned by the response? Use fiddler or something to see the original response. If its invalid, is there whitespace at the beginning of the response body?

Comment: You can also use [ThrowOnDeserializationError](https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html) to see the error (if there is one)

Comment: Hi @Yitz ,thanks for the headsup after breaking my head arround and activating the ThrowOnDeserializationError it seems that I had incorrectly set the type for "ExpirationTime" instead of int to string and this resulted the data being Null. Thanks again